# How to change header to \textsc

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    %\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Share\LaTeX}
    %\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\thechapter}
    %\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\leftmark}
    %\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\textsc{\chaptername
        \ \thechapter.\ #1}}{}
}


\begin{document}
\newpage

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\textsc{\chaptername
            \ \thechapter.\ #1}}{}
}

\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\input{Chapters/Introduction}


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}


\end{document}
```

That's a base of what I have right now. Don't want to post all of it since it's probably too long and unnecessary. The pagestyle types the name of the chapter at the top of the page in small caps. However, when I get to the references page it just types REFERENCES in all caps. Am I missing something?

EDIT:

Here's some images:
[image: First page looks good, small caps at work]

[image: References have all caps, looks terrible]

First page looks good, small caps at work!

References have all caps, looks terrible

Comment: I can't compile your file because I don't have the required files, but try adding `\nouppercase` in your`\fancyhead`-call. E.g. `\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}`

Comment: I used `\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsc{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}` and was able to achieve my goal. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your given code can be minimalized as I did in the following MWE. The definition of class `report` for `fancyhdr` is to use uppercase letters. You therefore need to add/use `\nouppercase`. To get what you want use `\textsc{\nouppercase\leftmark}` in the definition for `fancyhdr`.

Please see the following MWE (important code marked with `<=======`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsc{\nouppercase\leftmark}} % <===============
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
}


\begin{document}
\newpage

\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum

\section{test}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

and the wished result:

[image: resulting page]